# I want to change a tabulated table html output in python

Tags: python, html, markdown, streamlit, python-tabulate

I am using streamlit and loading data that I would like to put into a table with more customization than is currently offered by st.dataframe and st.table.

Below I use the tabulate package to change my data (after manipulating it with pandas) into an html table. My data is large so not something that I would like to type out. This is shown below with random data.

I then would like to add to the basic html template that is produced with my data things like a custom header and a larger font and a height for the table, however I can't seem to find a way to access the html stored in test2. I can wrap things around it (shown below) but can't get into the   which is stored in test2.

Any thoughts on how to add to a tabulated tables output html would be helpful

```
import tabulate as tb
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

data = {
    'A': np.random.rand(100),
    'B': np.random.randint(1, 100, size=100),
    'C': np.random.choice(['X', 'Y', 'Z'], size=100)
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

test2=tb.tabulate(data, tablefmt='html')

test3 = f'<div style="height: 150; overflow: auto">{test2}</div>'

st.markdown(test3, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Comment: `tabulate` has a `headers` parameter, and font/height can be changed by outputting custom CSS. Have you considered these options?

Comment: first: you can always use `CSS` to format elements in `HTML`. Second: `df.to_html()` generates HTML with table without using `tabulate`. And `df.style` has functions to format table before `to_html()`.

Answer (score 1):

`tabulate` has options `headers` and `showindex`

```
table = tb.tabulate(data, tablefmt='html', headers=df.columns, showindex=True)

st.markdown(table, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

[image]

Source code: [tabulate](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate/blob/master/tabulate/__init__.py#L1572)

---

You can also add `CSS` to change it

```
table = tb.tabulate(data, tablefmt='html', headers=df.columns, showindex=True)

st.write('<style>table th {font-size: 30px; color: red} table tr:nth-child(odd) td {background-color: #eee}</style>', unsafe_allow_html=True)

st.markdown(table, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

[image]

---

But you may also use `DataFrame` to generate `HTML` without `tabulate`.
And it may use `df.style` with many functions to format every cell.

This example changes background for `maximal` and `minimal` value in columns `A` and `B`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def highlight_max(x, props):
    return np.where(x == np.nanmax(x.to_numpy()), props, None)
def highlight_min(x, props):
    return np.where(x == np.nanmin(x.to_numpy()), props, None)

df = df.style \
        .apply(highlight_max, props='background-color: #fed', subset=['A','B'], axis=0) \
        .apply(highlight_min, props='background-color: #afa', subset=['A','B'], axis=0)

html = df.to_html()

st.write(html, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

[image]

---

Full code:

```
import tabulate as tb
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

data = {
    'A': np.random.rand(5),
    'B': np.random.randint(1, 100, size=5),
    'C': np.random.choice(['X', 'Y', 'Z'], size=5)
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def highlight_max(x, props):
    return np.where(x == np.nanmax(x.to_numpy()), props, None)
def highlight_min(x, props):
    return np.where(x == np.nanmin(x.to_numpy()), props, None)

df = df.style \
        .apply(highlight_max, props='background-color: #fed', subset=['A','B'], axis=0) \
        .apply(highlight_min, props='background-color: #afa', subset=['A','B'], axis=0)

html = df.to_html()

st.write(html, unsafe_allow_html=True)

table = tb.tabulate(data, tablefmt='html', headers=df.columns, showindex=True)
st.write('<style>table th {font-size: 30px; color: red} table tr:nth-child(odd) td {background-color: #eee}</style>', unsafe_allow_html=True)
st.markdown(table, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```